# Has Microsoft removed Visual Studio 2012 Express links for good?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, download, visual-studio-express

Recently I've been trying to download Visual Studio 2012 Express, but I failed to find it. One day the links were there, and the next day all of them were replaced by 2013 editions. Even Google and Microsoft's own search in their Downloads site find 2012 editions, but when I open links I see that they are 2013 now.

Why did Microsoft do that? I find it strange that they removed 2012 links, especially because 2010 links are still there.

See for yourself:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads

**Where do I get Visual Studio 2012 Express now?** We have a bunch of projects in TFS which we don't want to convert to 2013 yet.

Comment: You can download it from here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/F/5/1F519CC5-0B90-4EA3-8159-33BFB97EF4D9/VS2012_WDX_ENU.iso

Comment: Thx @T0m3kk, the only link that is working right now.

Comment: Thank you @user546774. The link you provided work for getting the 2012 desktop express edition. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I also think the answer to this question is on the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for windows desktop? This should work

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34673

Latest edit:

Old versions of visual studio are available here now

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid that they have "fixed" all the links to 2012; good thing that they left them available at least on the general Downloads site. For some reason, Google seems to burry that site somewhere deep in the results. I guess, they'll bubble up when Google reindexes VS downloads and finds that there is no 2012 any more. Still, that's a weird move from Microsft.

Comment: Is it only for Windows Development or does it support web development?

Comment: @stylojack_10 only windows development. If you want to do web development in 2012 then you'll need https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30669

Comment: Isn't there a combined one (express) that can be used to develop both windows and web apps like other versions of VS?

Comment: @stylojack_10 Not in 2012 for whatever reason...

Comment: Those links are not working anymore.

Comment: if you're still looking @Toat then i've updated the answer

Comment: VS2012 for Windows Desktop kan be downloaded from here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/F/5/1F519CC5-0B90-4EA3-8159-33BFB97EF4D9/VS2012_WDX_ENU.iso
It is the Offline Installer. I'm still looking for the Web version.

Comment: I am not able to find the web version! :(

Comment: @Shad see updated answer

Comment: yes, I looked into the same but still web version was not able. Thanks for the update though

Comment: @Shad "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web" is listed under the 2012 download though. Does microsoft have incorrect information on their site?

Comment: @5uperdan It is listed but once you go through the download list, it is not present. So yes, they have incorrect information perhaps not updated.

Answer (score 4):

You still can access installers through [Download Center](http://search.microsoft.com/en-US/DownloadResults.aspx?q=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Express%202012).

Comment: This appears to be no longer true

Answer (score 1):

Found this page searching for "Visual Studio 2012 Express not downloading"... When it did not work in Google Chrome!
If above solutions still don't work, try downloading with Internet Explorer!

Worked for me :)

Download [for Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34673) or [choose your edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2).

Comment: Thanks, "for Desktop" link works but "choose your edition" again contains only 2013 and 2010 editions, and some updates to 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be installed via [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)