# Install Team Explorer for VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

I've a VS2012 installation that doesn't have any `Team Menu`. Since it lacks `Team Explorer` I tried to install it, but it seems like it's not available to download nowadays.

I could found a language pack [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30659), and among the related links below you can see

> [Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255948)

However this link is broken.

How can I manage to install Team Explorer for this `VS2012`? I can't change my VS to any newer version so I have to stick to it.

### Screeshots

View menu (nor here nor in the sub-menu `other windows` does Team Explorer appear):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the list of elements in the [VS2012 installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/vs/older-downloads/), I guessed that it would be posible to install `Team Explorer` using the installer.

However, I have not the `VS2012 Installer` because it was not installed by my, but by my company IT department.

Then, I managed to get a `VS2012 Express edition` installer, and used it, hoping that it would include `Team Explorer`. In fact **it does**, so now I've it available for use in my `VS2012 Premium` edition.

For those in my same situation, I found the [ISO](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/F/5/1F519CC5-0B90-4EA3-8159-33BFB97EF4D9/VS2012_WDX_ENU.iso) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448878/has-microsoft-removed-visual-studio-2012-express-links-for-good).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for the 2012 but for the 2017
In the menu View ==> Team Explorer or ctrl + µ, ctrl + M

Comment: Thanks Tom, but like as I said, I've no option for Team Explorer right now. I'll update with a screenshot to make it more clear.